# SOAP validateUser not working

Tags: android, soap

I am trying to use SOAP 2.4 to validate a username and password using Android. I get a response from the server, I can confirm this as MySQL server confirmed my application made a request. However as you can see below I pass two parametres using the addProperty() method. MySQL server sees the request, but the values are null. As a result, I get a response saying "invalid username or password" however the username and password that I have hard coded is definitly in the database. Am I definitly passing the parametres correctly?

```
else {

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); // set
                                                                        // up
                                                                        // request

        request.addProperty("User", "raji"); // variable name, value. I got
                                                // the variable name, from
                                                // the wsdl file!
        request.addProperty("Password", "PASSWORD");

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11); // put all required data into a soap
                                        // envelope
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request); // prepare request
        AndroidHttpTransport httpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);
        httpTransport.debug = true;
        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope); // send request

        SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();            System.out.println(result);


    }
```

Here is the SOAP XML file

```
             <s:element name="ValidateUser">
              - <s:complexType>
             - <s:sequence>
               <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="User" type="s:string" /> 
                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Password" type="s:string" /> 
                   </s:sequence>
               </s:complexType>
                     </s:element>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution code is here. I did not add the .net code

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); // set
        request.addProperty("User", sUserName); // variable name, value. I
                                                // got
        request.addProperty("Password", sPassword);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11); // put all required data into a soap
        // envelope
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request); // prepare request
        AndroidHttpTransport httpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);
        httpTransport.debug = true;
        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope); // send request

        System.out.println("HERE IS THE ENVELOPE "
                + envelope.getInfo("User", "Password"));
        SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
```